# what string library should I used to parse specific data from bracket

Tags: lua

I parse a series of string from a log file,

but some of their format is different, ex.

```
...
[01. sample1][YES][1]
[02. sample1][2]
[03. sample1][NO][3]
...
```

I wanna parse the string like

```
...
01. sample1 YES
02. sample1
03. sample1 NO
...
```

really have no idea to achieve this.
please give me some idea! thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? How would you like the tags to be stored? Right now, it looks like you just want `"[01. sample1][YES][1]"` -> `"01. sample1 YES"`, still one string, but losing the brackets and any form of brackets that only contain numbers.

Comment: hi Advert, yes, I would like to get a string, but the point is the pattern which can be used on three bracket data and two bracket data. moteus's answer is a good idea, and I am still thinking.

Comment: Try `str:match'^%[(.-)]%[?(.-)]?%[.-]$'`

Comment: Hi Egor, thanks for your answer, I found something weird, if I used `print (log_decode(myStr))` which is work perfectly, but if I used a string variable like `local text = log_decode(myStr)` then print it, it will only show the data from first bracket, please help...

Comment: Try `local text1, text2 = log_decode(myStr)`

Comment: thanks Egor, work perfectly!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
function log_decode(str)
  local a,b,c = str:match("^%[(.-)%]%[(.-)%]%[(.-)%]$")
  if a then return a, b, c end
  return str:match("^%[(.-)%]%[(.-)%]$")
end

print(log_decode"[01. sample1][YES][1]")
print(log_decode"[02. sample1][2]")
print(log_decode"[03. sample1][NO][3]")
```

Comment: thanks moteus, the three bracket data work like a charm, but the two brackets data still print two infomation. thanks again!!